# are there read spinlock and write spinlock?

Tags: c, linux, locking

Like

```
pthread_rwlock_t lock;
pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&lock);
pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&lock);
```

Are the similar lock in spinlock?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a read lock and a write lock is, that a read lock is *shared* (i.e. can be acquired by multiple threads), but the write lock is *exclusive* (can only be acquired if *no* other locks are in effect).

The pthread spinlock interface only supports *exclusive* locks with `pthread_spin_lock()`, so this is not possible out of the box. You could however emulate the behaviour described above by maintaining an appropriate (counter) structure and using `pthread_spin_trylock()` (access to this structure must of course be synchronized, too). This might, however, counter the big advantage of "lightweightness" of spinlocks.